# delphi: run process as user and SYSTEM account environment variables

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need to run a process under the current user from another process that runs under SYSTEM (system process runs another process as current user).

I can run it with this code, but there is an issue with environment variables.. e.g. in the new 'user-mode' process, I see that the APPDATA value is C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming instead of C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming

```
function RunProcessAsCurrentUser(FileName: string): Boolean;
var
  ProcessId: Integer;
  hWindow, hProcess, TokenHandle: THandle;
  si: Tstartupinfo;
  p: Tprocessinformation;
begin
    Result := False;
    hWindow := FindWindow('Progman', 'Program Manager');
    GetWindowThreadProcessID(hWindow, @ProcessID);
    hProcess := OpenProcess (PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcessID);
    if OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, TokenHandle) then
    begin

      FillChar(si,SizeOf(si),0);
      with Si do begin
        cb := SizeOf( Si);
        dwFlags := startf_UseShowWindow;
        wShowWindow := SW_NORMAL;
        lpDesktop := PChar('winsta0\default');
      end;

      Result :=  CreateProcessAsUser(TokenHandle, nil,
        PChar('"'+FileName+'"'),
        nil, nil, false, Create_default_error_mode, nil, nil, si, p);
    end;
end;
```

the issue is actual in win7,8,10

I supposed that all process settings are copied from explorer.exe (and new process runs as user in the TaskManager) but looks like something stays from the SYSTEM...  Please help to resolve

Comment: Suggestion: use Delphi `ShellExecute()` and Windows `runas`: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/419-run-different-user.html

Comment: Note that using `runas` will invoke a UAC elevation prompt, whereas `CreateProcessAsUser()` will not.

Answer (score 2):

When using `CreateProcessAsUser()`, you should retrieve the user's environment using [`CreateEnvironmentBlock()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270.aspx):

> Retrieves the environment variables for the specified user. This block can then be passed to the `CreateProcessAsUser` function.

Pass that value to the `lpEnvironment` parameter of `CreateProcessAsUser()`.  Otherwise, the new process inherits the environment of the calling process instead.

For example:

```
function RunProcessAsCurrentUser(FileName: string): Boolean;
var
  ProcessId: Integer;
  hWindow, hProcess, TokenHandle: THandle;
  si: Tstartupinfo;
  p: Tprocessinformation;
  lpEnvironment: Pointer;
begin
  Result := False;

  hWindow := FindWindow('Progman', 'Program Manager');
  if hWindow = 0 then Exit;

  GetWindowThreadProcessID(hWindow, @ProcessID);
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, ProcessID);
  if hProcess = 0 then Exit;

  try
    if not OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, TokenHandle) then Exit;

    FillChar(si,SizeOf(si),0);
    with Si do begin
      cb := SizeOf( Si);
      dwFlags := startf_UseShowWindow;
      wShowWindow := SW_NORMAL;
      lpDesktop := PChar('winsta0\default');
    end;

    lpEnvironment := nil;
    CreateEnvironmentBlock(@lpEnvironment, TokenHandle, FALSE);
    try
      Result := CreateProcessAsUser(TokenHandle, nil,
        PChar('"'+FileName+'"'),
        nil, nil, FALSE, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,
        lpEnvironment, nil, si, p);
    finally
      DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! Btw, our tests show, that CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT should be used instead of CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE. and CreateEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment, TokenHandle, FALSE); instead of CreateEnvironmentBlock(@lpEnvironment, TokenHandle, FALSE);